# LogisticRegressionCV gives different answer even if the seed is set

Tags: python, logistic-regression, cross-validation, seed

I have a program which implements KFold in Logistic RegressionCV. I have set up a seed and use that in both KFOLD and LogisticRegressionCV. Even if the seed is set, I get a different measure of all my metrics every time I re-run the kernel. Here is the code:

```
    rs = random.seed(42)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_smt, y_smt, test_size=0.1, 
                                                    random_state=42)
    kf = KFold(n_splits=15, shuffle=flase, random_state=42)
    logistic = LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=2, fit_intercept=True, cv=kf, verbose =1, random_state=42)
    logistic.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("Train Coefficient:" , logistic.coef_) #weights of each feature
    print("Train Intercept:" , logistic.intercept_) #value of intercept
    print("\n \n \n ")


    logistic.predict(X_test)
    test_precision = metrics.precision_score(y_test, logistic.predict(X_test))
    test_avg_precision = metrics.average_precision_score(y_test, logistic.predict(X_test))
```

What can be a reason of that and if there is a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

According to SKlearn document [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold): `Randomized CV splitters may return different results for each call of split. You can make the results identical by setting random_state to an integer`.

However, it might only set the fold random state but not shuffling. Try setting `shuffle=False` and see if you still get different result.

Comment: I have changed the main question and also the code in it as per your suggestion. It still gives me different answers every time.